# Config server datasource connection @RefreshScope

Tags: spring, spring-data, datasource, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a config server and several clients.

Here is my configuration setup:

```java
@Component
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "params")
public class ConfigParams {

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> datasource;

    // here are some other properties not related to db
}
```

Also I have `spring.cloud.refresh.extra-refreshable=javax.sql.DataSource`. So, when some of configuration params are changed, all beans with @RefreshScope are recreated (that works fine). But even if the datasource property wasn't changed, the connection to the database was closed and opened. That's awful.

So, I would like a datasource bean to be recreated only if the corresponding properties change. Not every time. Can you please help me with that?

I'll be grateful for your help.

Comment: You can't use refresh scope for that. It's all or nothing. You could listen for an `EnvironmentChangeEvent` and inspect the keys and recreate the datasource on your own.

Comment: @spencergibb If I listen to an ``EnvironmentChangeEvent`` in datasource config class, bean will be recreated only if datasource params were changed? Can you please show an example in the answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have an example or time to come up with one.